# How can I group by day, and still return a datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to track the users in my db, when they was created to show it in a awesome chart. Each user has a column "Created" that is the DateTime when they was created. Right down to the time that day. 
However, for my chart I dont really care about the time, just the day, month and year. Is there a way I can return a datetime and count when I use datepart as the following:

```
SELECT datepart(year,Created), datepart(month,Created), datepart(day,Created), COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM [dbms].[User]
GROUP BY datepart(year,Created), datepart(month,Created), datepart(day,Created)
```

This returns three columns for year, month and day. Is there any way I could make it sexy and make it return DateTime (in YYYY/MM/DD format) and the cound?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or later, you can take advantage of the `date` data type.

```
SELECT cast(Created as date), COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM [dbms].[User]
GROUP BY cast(Created as date)
```

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or earlier:

```
SELECT dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,Created), 0), COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM [dbms].[User]
GROUP BY dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,Created), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, Created), 0) as date, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM [dbms].[User]
GROUP BY dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, Created), 0)
```

This will group you users by the creation date without time and will works on each versions of SQL Server. Among this, the Dateadd operation is more faster that casting...